# Which search index should be used with php and postgresql clustered

Tags: php, search, full-text-search

When writing a PHP application which search index should be used if you want to index a lot of documents in a clustered fashion. Is there a simple library to do the job? Is there something like lucene for php?

Answer (score 0):

About Lucene and PHP, there is [`Zend_Search_Lucene`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.html), which is part of the [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/) *(Which means well tested, well supported, well programmed, quite well documented... But might also means some work if you want to use it without the rest of the framework...)*.

Note that, quoting the doc :

> Zend_Search_Lucene is a general
>   purpose text search engine written
>   entirely in PHP 5. Since it stores its
>   index on the filesystem and does not
>   require a database server, it can add
>   search capabilities to almost any
>   PHP-driven website.

Which means you don't depend on anything else than PHP -- which may be nice too.

Comment: Does Zend_Lucene work with more than one host for your application? I read the docs and it says that it can not be used on e.g. nfs because of flock. Is it the same for clusterfs?